$\int_A \partial_t \vec{B} d\vec{A}= -\int_A (\nabla \times \vec{E})d\vec{A} \overset{?}\implies \partial_t \vec{B}= -\nabla \times \vec{E}$
In my physics class we recently derived faraday´s law: $\partial_t \vec{B}= -\nabla \times \vec{E}$. During the derivation my professor made the following conclusion $$\int_A \partial_t \vec{B} d\vec{A}= -\int_A (\nabla \times \vec{E})d\vec{A} \implies  \partial_t \vec{B}= -\nabla \times \vec{E}$$
However I am not sure why this should be correct. It is clear that $\int f(x)dx=\int g(x)dx$ does not have to imply f(x)=g(x). So why is the statement above true without any restrictions? I noticed that these type of argumentations come up very often in my theoretical physics class.

$\int_A f(x),\mathrm{d}x=\int_A g(x),\mathrm{d}x$ for all "reasonably nice" sets $A$ implies that $f=g$. (Why? This freedom of choice on the domain essentially allows "differentiating" the integral.) I am pretty sure the surface $A$ there is assumed to be quite arbitrary enough so that an analogous statement holds true.

so because we were allowed to differentiate under the integral sign we can assume that the statement is true?

It is not about differentiating under the integral sign; Rather, it is the fact that $$\frac{1}{\text{size}(A)}\int_A f(x),\mathrm{d}x \xrightarrow{\text{as “$A \to x$”}} f(x),$$ i.e., the integral divided by the size of the domain represents the average value, which then tends to the value at point as the domain shrinks to the point. This is essentially a kind of differentiation.

this makes sense! thank you very much

Move the equation to one side, yielding $\int_A (\partial_t \vec{B} + \nabla \times \vec{E}) d\vec{A}= 0$, if this is to hold for every $A$, then $\partial_t \vec{B} + \nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$, do you see why?
If not, imagine what would happen if the latter result was not true, then you could find a point $p$, where this is not zero. Because the function is smooth (by assumption), it must then be non-zero in some neighbourhood around $p$, yielding a non-zero integral, contradicting the statement. $Q.E.D.$
Of course, we're assuming the function is smooth (or at the very least, differentiable once, because a derivative is used).
